# Spring MongoDB - org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am evaluating MongoDB and Spring Data MongoDB in a spring boot application for one of our upcoming project. I have a simple POJO which would be saved in MongoDB

```
@Document(collection = "customers")
public class CustomerDoc{
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
private String Id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private MonetaryAmount amount;

    public CustomerDoc(String firstName, String lastName, MonetaryAmount    amount){
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
         this.amount = amount;
       }
}
```

The Spring configuration is

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDbName);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter());
}

@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter() throws Exception {
    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
    MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);
    mongoConverter.setMapKeyDotReplacement("\\:");
    return mongoConverter;
}
```

In the configuration, I have to set the replacement key because without having it, I get exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Map key java.lang.Class contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!

This happens because of the `MonetaryAmount` object in the `Customer` class

The customer repository is :

```
public interface CustomerDocRepository extends MongoRepository<CustomerDoc, String>{

    public List<CustomerDoc> findByFirstName();
}
```

Now if I try to save a customer object, I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:675)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
>       at com.poc.mongodb.MongoDbApp.main(MongoDbApp.java:43)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class.
>       at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
>       at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
>       at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:210)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encodeMap(DBObjectCodec.java:220)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.writeValue(DBObjectCodec.java:196)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:128)
>       at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.encode(DBObjectCodec.java:61)
>       at com.mongodb.CompoundDBObjectCodec.encode(CompoundDBObjectCodec.java:48)
>       at com.mongodb.CompoundDBObjectCodec.encode(CompoundDBObjectCodec.java:27)
>       at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
>       at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:101)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:43)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:129)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.sendMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:212)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:101)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:67)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:37)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
>       at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.insertCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:115)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.InsertOperation.executeCommandProtocol(InsertOperation.java:76)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:141)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
>       at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
>       at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
>       at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:239)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1054)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1049)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:462)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDBObjectList(MongoTemplate.java:1049)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsertBatch(MongoTemplate.java:935)

I am using mongo driver 3.2.2 Spring data MongoDB  1.9.1

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: The stacktrace appears as you are trying to convert a object that has a field with type java.lang.Class.  Please post the source for MonetaryAmount class.  Also, the fact that you have to set the dot replacement is due to something have a key value of "java.lang.Class", as in if you were typing into the Mongo console something like:  db.someCollection.insert({"java.lang.Class": "blah"})

Comment: MonetaryAmount is jsr354 api. [link](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/money/MonetaryAmount.java)

Comment: @JonPeterson can you please help me figure out a related problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023866/jaxbelement-providing-codec-converter-for-class-java-lang-class ... Although I understand that JAXBElement in my question has a field with type java.lang.Class, how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: @ShahidAkhter did you ever manage to fix this? Facing the same issue in 2020