# JAXBElement: providing codec (/converter?) for class java.lang.Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have been evaluating to adopt spring-data-mongodb for a [project](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku). In summary, my aim is:

1. Using existing XML schema files to generate Java classes.

   - This is achieved using [JAXB xjc](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/tree/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/models/schema)
   - The root class is [TSDProductDataType](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/blob/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/models/schema/TSDProductDataType.java) and is further modeled as below:

[image: XML Schema Model]

The thing to note here is that [ExtensionType](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/blob/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/models/schema/ExtensionType.java#L53) contains `protected List<Object> any;` allowing it to store Objects of any class. In my case, it is amongst the classes named TSD**Module_Name_Here**ModuleType and can be browsed [here](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/tree/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/models/schema)

2. Use spring-data-mongodb as persistence store

   - This is achieved using a simple [ProductDataRepository](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/blob/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/models/ProductDataRepository.java)

     ```
     @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "product", path = "product")
     public interface ProductDataRepository extends MongoRepository<TSDProductDataType, String> {
         TSDProductDataType queryByGtin(@Param("gtin") String gtin);
     }
     ```
   - The unmarshalled **TSDProductDataType**, however, contains JAXBElement which spring-data-mongodb doesn't seem to handle by itself and throws a [CodecConfigurationException](https://github.com/oliot-tsd/tsd-heroku/blob/master/src/main/java/org/oliot/heroku/tsd/controllers/HomeController.java#L71) `org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class.`

Here is the faulty statement:

```
TSDProductDataType tsdProductDataType = jaxbElement.getValue();
repository.save(tsdProductDataType);
```

[image: Output in Debugger]

I tried playing around with Converters for spring-data-mongodb as explained [here](https://pbatey.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/jaxbelement-and-mongo/), however, it seems I am missing something since the exception is about "Codecs" and not "Converters".

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

**Adding converters for JAXBElement**

**Note:** Works with version 1.5.6.RELEASE of org.springframework.boot::spring-boot-starter-parent. With version 2.0.0.M3, hell breaks loose

It seems that I missed something while trying to add converter earlier. So, I added it like below for testing:

```
@Component
@ReadingConverter
public class JAXBElementReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, JAXBElement> {
    //@Autowired
    //MongoConverter converter;

    @Override
    public JAXBElement convert(DBObject dbObject) {
        Class declaredType, scope;
        QName name = qNameFromString((String)dbObject.get("name"));
        Object rawValue = dbObject.get("value");
        try {
            declaredType = Class.forName((String)dbObject.get("declaredType"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            if (rawValue.getClass().isArray()) declaredType = List.class;
            else declaredType = LinkedHashMap.class;
        }
        try {
            scope = Class.forName((String) dbObject.get("scope"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            scope = JAXBElement.GlobalScope.class;
        }
        //Object value = rawValue instanceof DBObject ? converter.read(declaredType, (DBObject) rawValue) : rawValue;
        Object value = "TODO";
        return new JAXBElement(name, declaredType, scope, value);
    }

    QName qNameFromString(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split("[{}]");
        if (parts.length > 2) return new QName(parts[1], parts[2], parts[0]);
        if (parts.length == 1) return new QName(parts[0]);
        return new QName("undef");
    }
}


@Component
@WritingConverter
public class JAXBElementWriteConverter implements Converter<JAXBElement, DBObject> {
    //@Autowired
    //MongoConverter converter;

    @Override
    public DBObject convert(JAXBElement jaxbElement) {
        DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
        dbObject.put("name", qNameToString(jaxbElement.getName()));
        dbObject.put("declaredType", jaxbElement.getDeclaredType().getName());
        dbObject.put("scope", jaxbElement.getScope().getCanonicalName());
        //dbObject.put("value", converter.convertToMongoType(jaxbElement.getValue()));
        dbObject.put("value", "TODO");
        dbObject.put("_class", JAXBElement.class.getName());
        return dbObject;
    }

    public String qNameToString(QName name) {
        if (name.getNamespaceURI() == XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI) return name.getLocalPart();
        return name.getPrefix() + '{' + name.getNamespaceURI() + '}' + name.getLocalPart();
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class TsdApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TsdApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                new JAXBElementReadConverter(),
                new JAXBElementWriteConverter()
        ));
    }
}
```

So far so good. However, how do I instantiate `MongoConverter converter;`?
`MongoConverter` is an interface so I guess I need an instantiable class adhering to this interface. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the desire for convenience in being able to just map an existing domain object to the database layer with no boilerplate, but even if you weren't having the JAXB class structure issue, I would still be recommending away from using it verbatim. Unless this is a simple one-off project, you almost definitely will hit a point where your domain models will need to change but your persisted data need to remain in an existing state. If you are just straight persisting the data, you have no mechanism to convert between a newer domain schema and an older persisted data scheme. Versioning of the persisted data scheme would be wise too.

The link you posted for writing the customer converters is one way to achieve this and fits in nicely with the Spring ecosystem. That method should also solve the issue you are experiencing (about the underlying messy JAXB data structure not converting cleanly).

Are you unable to get that method working? Ensure you are loading them into the Spring context with `@Component` plus auto-class scanning or manually via some `Configuration` class.

**EDIT to address your EDIT:**

Add the following to each of your converters:

```
private final MongoConverter converter;

public JAXBElement____Converter(MongoConverter converter) {
    this.converter = converter;
}
```

Try changing your bean definition to:

```
@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions(@Lazy MongoConverter converter) {
    return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
            new JAXBElementReadConverter(converter),
            new JAXBElementWriteConverter(converter)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a simple one-off project for now. So, I'd like to keep it a bare minimum (Also, the XSD files are already provided by a standardization body so probably version approach will work best).

I tried to write the converters again following the URL that I quoted. It seems my problem was an incompatibility between v1.5.6 and v2.0.0 of spring-boot-starter templates (the code provided in URL was for v1.5.6). And I updated this in my answer.

However, I am now stuck in getting my head wrapped around `MongoConverter converter;`. Any suggestion on how to instantiate it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's going to be instantiated by the Spring Data Mongo and just needs to be wired in via the bean definition.  Alternatively you could define each converter as a bean and autowire it in, but the way above in my edited answer is probably cleaner.

Comment: There seems to be a circular dependency https://gist.github.com/gvkalra/444f0e1c6b345cd7f6cda4a582641384

Comment: Try using lazy loading on either the parameter or method for the bean definition. `@Lazy @Bean` or `@Lazy MongoConverter converter`.

Comment: `@Lazy MongoConverter converter` worked!... Spring just seems to be magic!

Comment: Just for your info, in the new version you need to change the DBObject with Document object otherwise it wont work